# PostgreSQL - Dynamic filter expression

Tags: postgresql, functions, where

Given a simple function (*SQL* for the sake of example, can be *plpgsql*)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_filter(
  f INT[] DEFAULT NULL
) RETURN INT[] LANGUAGE SQL AS
  $$
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(val)
    FROM   table
    WHERE  <filer>
    ;
  $$
;
```

**what is the most efficient way** to

- **either** filter by elements in `f`, if `f IS NOT NULL`
- **or** else use *no filter* at all

I am not bound to using an `ARRAY` if any kind of set structure is favorable.

---

I am currently using a simple `CASE` as `<filter>`:

```
CASE WHEN f IS NULL THEN val > 0 ELSE val = ANY(f) END
```

in favor of e.g. *dynamic SQL*/`FORMAT`, but I wonder if there is a more natural solution alike the concept of

```
WHERE [TRUE | <filter_expression>]
```

in the context of arrays, or sets of any suitable kind.

---

*PostgreSQL > 12*